# I need to fade in a page section using jQuery inside asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to make a div inside my page fade in as soon as the page loads but I'm not getting any results. I've tried referencing the jQuery and js scripts directly in the content pages to no avail.  It is my opinion that it should work fine if I have the scripts referenced in the master page since other functions I have inside the js script are working fine.  I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and how to get this fade in effect to work.This is my code:

**index.aspx**(Content Page)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Frontend.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" %>
        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
        </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
            <div id="main-content">
                ...
            </div>
```

**Frontend.master**(Master Page)

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Frontend.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPages_Frontend" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Some title</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="main-page-container">
                <div class="col-md-3" id="nav-pane">
                    <nav class="navbar">
                        <div class="">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked mr-auto" id="main-nav">
                                <li class="active" id="home"><a href="../index.aspx">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="" id="aboutMe"><a href="../ContentPages/aboutMe.aspx">About Me</a></li>
                                <li class="" id="works"><a href="../ContentPages/works.aspx">Works</a></li>
                                <li class="" id="works"><a href="../ContentPages/skills.aspx">Skills</a></li>
                                <%--<li class="" id="contactMe"><a href="../ContentPages/contactMe.aspx">Contact Me</a></li>--%>
                        </div>
                </ul>

                    </nav>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9" id="content-area">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/JavaScript.js"></script>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {   

    //Content Fade in
    $('.navbar .nav li a').click(function () {
        $('#recent-achievements').fadeIn(3000);
    });

});
```

Comment: `bootstrap.js` requires `jquery.js` loaded first.

Comment: ASP.NET has nothing to do with this. Why does your HTML code not have a single HTML element with the attribute id="recent-achievements"

Comment: Sorry Brian.  I forgot to include the <div> that has the id of recent achievements.  It is inside of the <div id="main-content">

Comment: Alex I changed the jquery.js to the head tag ahead of bootstrap.js, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something basic, make the element you want to fade-in "hidden" in your html:

```
<div id="element-to-fadein" hidden>Recent achievements</div>
```

and on 'document ready' just fade it in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('#element-to-fadein').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Also, as an aside, you reference:

```
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

in `<head>` before you reference jQuery at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/JavaScript.js"></script>
```

You should make sure you reference jQuery first and have other scripts below that reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't need to add "hidden" attribute to achieve fading effect in jquery. He is just not including the jquery script inside the head tag

Comment: @Sam R Heh, thanks - you could mark it as the answer and give it an upvote and I'm all yours!

Comment: @RickLiguz I marked it as the answer but since my rep is so low it doesn't show my upvote publicly.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
body {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500 ease;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
   setTimeout(function() {
       document.body.style.opacity = 1
   }, 250)
})
```

Comment: Tried this and it isn't producing any fade in effect.